# Dante socks5 does't work from an external server

Tags: socks, dante

I use  [Dante socks5 proxy for telegram](https://github.com/schors/tgdante2)

And have a problem with an external server:

```
curl -v -x socks5://user:password@localhost:1080 https://web.telegram.org
* Rebuilt URL to: https://web.telegram.org/
*   Trying localhost...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to localhost port 1080 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using this command to allow a port

```
sudo ufw allow 1080
```