# Not able to connect to dante socks 5 proxy server

Tags: android, socks, dante

hi i have installed the Dante proxy in remote server and trying to connect to in but connection itself is getting failed. Also there is no logs printed in the server.

I have used this [socks5](https://github.com/btoll/socks5-client) client to connect to the server by giving the server ip address with 9050 port

and applied the fixes suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585398/dante-socks5-doest-work-from-an-external-server) but no luck

can anyone please help me to identify the issue where i am went wrong to make it successful

Answer (score -1):

Hi I found answer for myself. This is the issue with authentication and firewall issue.

Thanks to buddy for creating [this](https://spark-in.me/post/vds-socks5-proxy-server) with clear steps and explanation